# Java method object name from argument

Tags: java, object, arguments

I would like to create a method, which will, besides other things, create an object named like the method argument. (I apologize if it is solved somewhere else, didn't find it) Something like as follows:

```
public return_type method (String ARGUMENT1)
{
  ...
  ClassOfSomeKind objectOfSomeKind someprefix_ARGUMENT1 = new ClassOfSomeKind();
}
```

Comment: As an aside, it's useful to make even your sample code follow naming conventions, e.g. `string objectName` as the parameter and `SomeClass` instead of `objectOfSomeKind`.

Comment: I think you need to explain why you want this.

Answer (score 3):

That's naming a *variable* - not an object. Objects don't have names, as such. (You can have a field called `name` of course, but it's not a *general* thing.)

Variable names are usually only relevant at compile time - so it doesn't really make sense to do this dynamically.

It sounds like you probably want a `Map<String, YourClassType>` so that you can associate each object with a name and then fetch it later. So something like:

```
class Foo {
    private final Map<String, Bar> bars = new HashMap<>();

    public Bar createBar(String name) {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bars.put(name, bar);
        return bar;
    }

    public void processBar(String name) {
        Bar bar = bars.get(name);
        if (bar == null) {
            // No Bar for that name...
            // Maybe throw an exception?
        }
        // Do something with bar
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but as i am a beginner, could you please explain a little? What i need is to create a "shortcut" function, which i use in different places in code, but everytime i use it, it creates same object type, but with unique content and i need to be able to get to those different objects later. Could you please extend my code with Map so i would iunderstand it better?

Comment: @user3338991: It's hard to do so when we know so little about what you're trying to achieve. I've added an example, but it's not entirely clear whether that's what you need...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Map where the key is your variable name and the value is ObjectOfSomeKind object:

```
public class YourClass {
  ...
  private Map<String, ObjectOfSomeKind> yourHashMap= new HashMap<String, ObjectOfSomeKind>();

  public method (string ARGUMENT1)
  {
    yourHashMap.put("someprefix_"+ARGUMENT1, new ObjectOfSomeKind ("someprefix_"+ARGUMENT1));

  }
  ...

  public retrieveMethod (string ARGUMENT1)
  {
    ObjectOfSomeKind objectOfSomeKindRetrieved = yourHashMap.get("someprefix_"+ARGUMENT1);
  }
}
```